# Unwanted question marks in noweb output

Tags: noweb

I have the following noweb file, titled `test`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{noweb}
\begin{document}
\section{Hello World}
This is a program

<<example.py>>=
print("Hello, world!")
@
\end{document}
```

I type the following commands:

```
pdflatex test.tex
evince test.pdf
```

The pdf looks something like this:

```
??    <example.py ??>=
         print("Hello, world!")
      This code is written to file example.py
```

What are these question marks and how do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run pdflatex test.tex a second time. The first run generates warnings about undefined cross-references. Those cross-references are defined in the generated aux file, which is then used with the second pass.